# Saying ברכת המזון with על הנסים after praying ערבית following Purim

Tags: halacha, purim, bentching, evening-night, al-hanissim

The סעודה I was partaking in on Purim day continued well into the evening of the next day (Shushan Purim here in the US). Teffilah with a minyan was only available immediately after צאת הכוכבים, so a number of us decided to say ברכת המזון - with על הנסים - and then pray ערבית (without על הנסים). However, we were left wondering: would it have been permissible to say ערבית *without* על הנסים, continue the meal and then say ברכת המזון with על הנסים? Or, would this be considered תרי דסתרי - since saying ערבית without על הנסים would seem to declare that Purim is over and would preclude going back and saying על הנסים afterwards.

During some initial discussion it was suggested that this case is different from a situation where Shabbat falls out on Erev Rosh Hodesh, since saying both רצה and יעלה ויבוא during ברכת המזון after having eaten on both Shabbat and Rosh Hodesh in the same  meal is not self contradictory in the same manner.

Can anyone point to sources of the הלכה for the scenario I have described?

Comment: See kovetz Halachos Rav Shmuel Kamentesky ,he discusses this,will post an answer when I can get to it.

Comment: The situation would not occur end of Shabbat if your seuda continued as you have not recited Maariv and doing so would require havdalah before you can eat anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Mishne Brurah (695, 16) cites a dispute among *Poskim* as to whether one may recite *Al Hanisim* in bentching after davening *Maariv* after *Purim* (where he does not say *Al Hanissim*). To avoid the disagreement he quotes *Magen Avraham* that one should *bentch* first and then daven *Maariv*.

Comment: And what if someone didn't do this? Should they not say?